# CSV: Change One Field Column

Tags: php, csv, optimization, fgetcsv, fputcsv

I have file named `test.csv` which has 85  fields?

I have to read that file, change 1 column & save it again.

I have below code.

```
$file_name = "test.csv";
$infos = array();
if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($data);

        $cleanURL = cleanUrl($data[6]);

        $infos[] = $data[0] . ',' . $data[1] . ',' . $data[2] . ',' . $data[3] . ',' . $data[4] . ',' . $data[5] . ',' . $data[6] . ',' . $data[7] . ',' . $data[8] . ',' . $data[9] . ',' . $data[10] . ',' . $data[11] . ',' . $data[12] . ',' . $data[13] . ',' . $data[14] . ',' . $data[15] . ',' . $data[16] . ',' . $cleanURL . ',' . $data[18] . ',' . $data[19] . ',' . $data[20] . ',' . $data[21] . ',' . $data[22] . ',' . $data[23] . ',' . $data[24] . ',' . $data[25] . ',' . $data[26] . ',' . $data[27] . ',' . $data[28] . ',' . $data[29] . ',' . $data[30] . ',' . $data[31] . ',' . $data[32] . ',' . $data[33] . ',' . $data[34] . ',' . $data[35] . ',' . $data[36] . ',' . $data[37] . ',' . $data[38] . ',' . $data[39] . ',' . $data[40] . ',' . $data[41] . ',' . $data[42] . ',' . $data[43] . ',' . $data[44] . ',' . $data[45] . ',' . $data[46] . ',' . $data[47] . ',' . $data[48] . ',' . $data[48] . ',' . $data[50] . ',' . $data[51] . ',' . $data[52] . ',' . $data[53] . ',' . $data[54] . ',' . $data[55] . ',' . $data[56] . ',' . $data[57] . ',' . $data[58] . ',' . $data[59] . ',' . $data[60] . ',' . $data[61] . ',' . $data[62] . ',' . $data[63] . ',' . $data[64] . ',' . $data[65] . ',' . $data[66] . ',' . $data[67] . ',' . $data[68] . ',' . $data[69] . ',' . $data[70] . ',' . $data[71] . ',' . $data[72] . ',' . $data[73] . ',' . $data[74] . ',' . $data[75] . ',' . $data[76] . ',' . $data[77] . ',' . $data[78] . ',' . $data[79] . ',' . $data[80] . ',' . $data[81] . ',' . $data[82] . ',' . $data[83] . ',' . $data[84] . ',' . $data[85];
        //echo $data[6].'->'.cleanUrl($data[6]);
        //print_r($data[17]);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$fp = fopen('write.csv', 'w');

foreach ($infos as $info) {
    fputcsv($fp, array($info), ',', ' ');
}

function cleanUrl($str, $replace = array(), $delimiter = '-') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    if (!empty($replace)) {
        $str = str_replace((array) $replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Is there any sorter way, so i don't need to write 85 columns in `#info` array? Because i'm going to change only 1 column & write it again.

If i have **Date** 10/10/2016, 10:15 AM.

then it separates both in different column.

`fputcsv($fp, array($info), ',', ' ');` here may be issue.

Comment: i could do it with less code, but basiclly i see no work around

Comment: Is it always going to be the same column that is changed? `$data[17] = cleanUrl($data[6])` ?

Answer (score 2):

less looping, should a little more efficient

```
<?php 


$file_name = "test.csv";
$infos = array();
if (($handle = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $fp = fopen('write.csv', 'w');

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        $data[17] = cleanUrl($data[6]);
        fputcsv($fp, array($data), ',', ' ');

    fclose($handle);
}

}

function cleanUrl($str, $replace = array(), $delimiter = '-') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
    if (!empty($replace)) {
        $str = str_replace((array) $replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Comment: note: that in the original code, `cleanUrl($data[6])` is later assigned in the place of `$data[17]`. `$data[6]` is reentered, unchanged